# Mansory works only after refreshing (jquery) (Ruby on rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My posts.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#posts').masonry itemSelector: '.box'
  $container = $('#posts')
  $container.imagesLoaded ->
    $container.masonry()
    return
  return
```

Work only after refreshing page, otherwise I have all posts in one column. One after the other. What Can I do? 
Thanks for answers

Comment: Help! I don't know what I do wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with using

> jquery-turbolinks gem

When I configured my app with jquery-turbolinks documentation my mansory gem works very well!